# Variance of the number of empty cells

Tags: probability

If I place $k$ balls in $n$ cells randomly with uniform probability, then for large enough $n$ and $k/n$ small enough, I expect about $n e^{-k/n}$ cells to be empty (using the Poisson approximation to the Binomial.)  However, I cannot find the limit of the variance of the number of empty cells?

One can compute explicit cases by using the probability that exactly $m$ cells are empty,
$$var = \sum_{m=0}^nm^2\binom{n}{m}\sum_{\nu=0}^{n-m}(-1)^\nu\binom{n-m}{\nu}\left(1-\frac{m+\nu}{n}\right)^k - \left(1 - \frac{1}{n}\right)^{2k}$$

but I cannot find the limit of this.

The same question can be asked of singletons, doubletons, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We use the method of *indicator functions*, which is often useful for this kind of problem.  Let $X_i=1$ if the $i$-th cell is empty, and $0$ otherwise. Let
$$Y=\sum_{i=1}^n X_i.$$
Then $Y$ is the number of empty cells. We want the variance of $Y$. This is equal to 
$$E(Y^2)-(E(Y))^2.$$
It is easy to find $E(Y)$, since we can find $P(X_i=1)$, and then use the linearity of expectation.

Now we want $E(Y^2)$.  To find it, expand $Y^2$, that is, $(X_1+\cdots +X_n)^2$. We get
$$\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2  + 2\sum_{1\le i<j\le n} X_iX_j.$$
Finding the expectation of $\sum X_i^2$, is easy, indeed we have already found it, since $X_i^2=X_i$.  It remains to find the expectation of $2\sum X_iX_j$.

There are $\binom{n}{2}$ terms in the sum. So we need to  find the expectation of a typical mixed term $X_iX_j$, and multiply by $2\binom{n}{2}$.
To find $E(X_iX_j)$, all we need to do is to find the probability that cells $i$ and $j$ are both empty. That is not hard to do.

**Comment:** The technique used bypasses the difficult problem of finding the probability distribution of $Y$, then getting an *expression* for the variance, and then somehow simplifying this expression so that we can actually use it for further work.

Note that our random variables $X_i$ are *not independent*. However, that need not be an impediment. The expectation $E(X_iX_j)$ is, in our problem,  somewhat  harder to calculate than if we had independence, but it is not *much* harder.

The technique will also work for the problems involving singletons, doubletons, etc., proposed in the post.

Answer (score 6):

Let $Y$ be the number of empty cells.  We can write $Y = \sum_{i=1}^n Y_i$ where $Y_i$ is $1$ if cell number $i$ is empty, $0$ otherwise.

$E(Y_j)$ is the probability that cell number $j$ is empty, namely $(1 - 1/n)^k$, so $E(Y) = n (1 - 1/n)^k$.

For two distinct cells $j_1$ and $j_2$, $E(Y_{j_1} Y_{j_2}$ is the probability that both are empty, namely
$(1 - 2/n)^k$.   There are $n(n-1)$ such ordered pairs.  On the other hand
$E(Y_j^2) = E(Y_j) = (1 - 1/n)^k$, and there are $n$ of these.  So
$E(Y^2) = n(n-1) (1 - 2/n)^k + n (1 - 1/n)^k$, and
$$\text{Var}(Y) = E(Y^2) - E(Y)^2 = n(n-1)(1 - 2/n)^k + n (1 - 1/n)^k - n^2 (1 - 1/n)^{2k}$$

As $n \to \infty$ with $k = \lambda n$, $(1 - 1/n)^k \approx (1 - \frac{\lambda}{2n}) e^{-\lambda} $,
$(1 - 1/n)^{2k} \approx (1 - \frac{\lambda}{n}) e^{-2\lambda}$
 and $(1 - 2/n)^k \approx (1 - 2 \lambda/n) e^{-2 \lambda}$.  The end result is $\text{Var}(Y) \approx  n (e^{-\lambda} - (1+\lambda) e^{-2\lambda})$.